# Allure reporting from Junit/XMl/Excel

Tags: javascript, xml, junit, allure, testcomplete

How to generate an Allure reporting from Xml or Junit or Excel file. I'm not using Selenium or POM.xml or Jenkins. I've a junit report from TestComplete 14.1, I wish to know how to generate allure report.

Downloading a Jar and upload in test complete and generate step by step. Please share the Allure Jar.
Convert XML to Allure.

Answer (score 1):

if you install the allure command line utility, you can invoke allure to either serve a report or generate a report file on your TestComplete xml file.

```
allure serve c:\path\to\your\testComplete\results
```

Or

```
allure generate c:\path\to\your\testComplete\results
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and here is the step by step solution for the same.

https://vallatestcomplete.wordpress.com/2019/06/28/allure-reporting-testcomplete-14-1/

Comment: Maybe reference where you got the information and include it in the answer so that the Question/Answer format of StackOverflow is preserved. Thanks.